# Вычленить (PHP) из строки нужные цифры и опубликовать в нормальном виде

Tags: php

Добрый день!

У меня поступают из базы вот такие переменные:
 1. a:1:{i:0;i:53;}
 2. a:2:{i:0;i:52;i:1;i:53;}
 3. a:1:{i:0;i:53;}
 4. a:1:{i:0;i:54;}

В них содержатся цифры 52, 53, 54, 55 и 56.

Мне нужно выловить их и показать пользователю уже нормальный вид.
 1. БББ
 2. ААА, БББ
 3. БББ
 4. ССС

Я понимаю, что можно тупо сделать - Если строка содержит 53, то показывай БББ. Это понятно. А вот когда есть комбинации, тут я тупить начинаю. Не писать же все возможные варианты... подскажите пожалуйста, что и как использовать?

Comment: ничего не понятно

Comment: Попробую понятнее объяснить.

У меня приходит вот такой столбец:

row[2]
a:1:{i:0;i:52;}
a:1:{i:0;i:52;}
a:1:{i:0;i:52;}
a:1:{i:0;i:52;}
a:2:{i:0;i:52;i:1;i:53;}
a:2:{i:0;i:52;i:1;i:53;}
a:2:{i:0;i:52;i:1;i:53;}
a:2:{i:0;i:52;i:1;i:53;}
a:2:{i:0;i:52;i:1;i:53;}
a:2:{i:0;i:52;i:1;i:53;}
a:2:{i:0;i:52;i:1;i:53;}
a:1:{i:0;i:52;}

Мне нужно, чтобы каждая строка этого столбца замещалась буквенным обозначением.

Если в строке есть цифры 52 и 53, то писалось бы ААА и БББ.
Если в строке только цифра 52, то только ААА.
Если 52 и 54, то ААА и ССС.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$str = 'a:2:{i:0;i:52;i:1;i:54;}';
$data = unserialize($str); // десериализуем
$map = [52 => 'AAA', 53 => 'BBB', 54 => 'CCC'];
foreach ($data as $k) {
    echo $map[$k]."\n"; // сопоставляем со строками
}
```

Вывод:

```
AAA
CCC
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, самое оно. А я в дебри полез))

Answer (score 1):

Трудно понять суть вашего вопроса, если я правильно понял, вам надо получить данные из строки, а т.к. строка - это данные которые cериализованы  `serialize`, для получения читаемого формата вам надо применить функцию `unserialize()`:

```
<?php
$str1 = 'a:1:{i:0;i:53;}';
$str2 = 'a:1:{i:0;i:53;}';
echo unserialize($str1);
echo unserialize($str2);


/*
результат $str1
array (
  0 => 53,
)

результат $str2 
array (
  0 => 52,
  1 => 53,
)
......

*/

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Додумался. Криво наверно, но работает. Если кто подскажет как правильнее написать буду очень благодарен.

```html
<?php

$a = 'a:2:{i:0;i:52;i:1;i:53;}';

if (strpos($a, '52') !== false) //  жесткое сравнение
{
    $ct1 = ААА;
    echo '52 Найдено';
} else {
    echo '52 Не найдено';
}

if (strpos($a, '53') !== false) 
{
    $ct2 = БББ;
    echo '53 Найдено';
} else {
    echo '53 Не найдено';
}


if (strpos($a, '54') !== false)
{
    $ct3 = ВВВ;
    echo '54 Найдено';
} else {
    echo '54 Не найдено';
}

if (strpos($a, '55') !== false)
{
    $ct4 = ГГГ;
    echo '55 Найдено';
} else {
    echo '55 Не найдено';
}

if (strpos($a, '56') !== false) 
{
    $ct5 = ДДД;
    echo '56 Найдено';
} else {
    echo '56 Не найдено';
}






$CTA = $ct1.'/ '.$ct2.'/ '. $ct3.'/ '. $ct4.'/ '.$ct5;
echo $CTA;

?>
```

Comment: В соседних ответах уже подсказали: `unserialize` вам в помощь